# How do I create and setup a network interface for Windows 10 on a VPS?

Tags: windows-10, networking, netsh

I've installed Windows 10 on a VPS machine. Now I'm connected to the virtual terminal to access RDP and it says no internet connection.

I've opened terminal and now looking at the interfaces so far, there is none. From what I can see online, there's lots of info on how to "reset" or "repair" and interface, but nothing about create one.

Can someone explain to me how I create the interface? I have my IPv4 static IP address, gateway and mask from my host.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What network interface does the VPS host emulate? Does it show up in Device Manager (devmgmt.msc)? Windows doesn't come with drivers for virtio network interfaces, you'd have to install those.

Comment: Open the "Ethernet Controller" device, then under Details look for the `PCI\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY` label that has the vendor/product IDs (Google will be able to translate it to an actual name). For example, Realtek NICs have VID_10EC, KVM VirtIO devices have VID_1AF4, but it might also be something else.

Comment: @user1686 Thanks, so I found that, then went "Update drivers" and then went into my iso and found NetKVM then picked my OS and architecture and the update worked and internet worked immediately. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, your host provides a network adapter that the VM simply doesn't have drivers for.

Instead of emulating an existing physical NIC model, many VM hosts provide "VirtIO" hardware which is better optimized for usage in VMs (this usually includes not just network interfaces but also VirtIO SCSI disks). It's very similar in purpose to Hyper-V's "Gen2" or "enlightened" virtual hardware.

Windows does not have any VirtIO drivers built in, so you will need to install them from Red Hat (either [here](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers) or [here](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/kvmnet/installer), I don't know which is more up to date) or alternatively ask your VM host to provide a different network interface type (Qemu-KVM can emulate several popular NIC models).